# Heartbeat, linked VIPs

Tags: linux, heartbeat

In Heartbeat, can I configure it so virtual IPs on different interfaces are linked together when it comes to failover? For example with:

```
foo1 8.8.8.1/24/eth0 10.0.0.1/24/eth1
```

If `eth0` were to fail, and cause foo2 to pick it up, the same would happen for `eth1` because `eth0` failed. The same would be true for the reverse as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  I have a set of external VIPs "paired" with a set of internal VIPs that have this same requirement.  I also have failover working in both directions.

Here's a look at my config and some explanation.  I've redacted the public IPs.

```
server1    10.0.9.1/24/eth0/10.0.9.255
server2    10.0.9.4/24/eth0/10.0.9.255
server1    x.y.z.2/27/eth0/x.y.z.31
server2    x.y.z.25/27/eth0/x.y.z.31
```

So, there are two internal floating VIPs, 10.0.9.1/24 and 10.0.9.4/24.  10.0.9.1/24 is primary on server1 and 10.0.9.4/24 is primary on server2.

For external VIPs, x.y.z.2/27 is primary on server1 and x.y.z.25/27 is primary on server2.

I just realized this but I am using the eth0 interface for all these IPs without issue.  In reality, the x.y.z.0/27 network is physically connecting to eth1.  Give it a shot.

EDIT:

See also keepalived/vrrpd and vrrp_sync_groups:

http://www.keepalived.org/LVS-NAT-Keepalived-HOWTO.html

http://www.keepalived.org/pdf/UserGuide.pdf